# Can't push salesforce managed package

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I am salesforce developer, but not good with managed packages and need some help.

We have one managed package we push it to our customer. We need to delete a few unused classes from the managed package and reupload the new version.
When we try to push the package to our existing customer we get the error below.

> you need the deleted class because it still refer in our old package which we already push to the client

Now the issue is we can't create the the unused class with same name, so we can't push to anyone with our new update.

Comment: Did you follow the documentation? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_managed_component_deletion.htm

Comment: Hi we follow it but one vf page is deleted and we upload it is there anyway we can get out of this situation its very critical for us please do help.

Comment: I suggest you provide more details by editing the original question - what steps you did, where did it fail. Your current description is too short and leaves lots to guess work. Also, since it is critical: open a ticket with Salesforce support. Lastly: are you aware there's a dedicated Salesforce forum https://salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi thanks for help. i do create case and i will try to explain with example when i push my latest version to my clients it gives me error "Salesforce has blocked this package upgrade because the new package version removes some Apex code that one or more Visualforce pages or global Visualforce components need in order to function. Please contact your partner with this error information. Provide these component names to your partner. Visualforce Page: TestPage." so now the issue is i cant create new TestPage in my org b'coz salesforce wont allow that and i cant even push it, i am so worried.